# Anyone used JSON1 extention in ionic angular?

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic3, sqlite-json1

I would like to retrieve SQlite data in JSON format using the JSON1 extension, however when i implement the code, i get the error message

> error{"message":"sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such function:
> json_object", "code":5}

Is there a plugin or library that will allow me to utilize this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that Capacitor's SQLite Plugin has this capability.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).